# How to connected 2 external monitors via Lenovo thinkpad dock to laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.1. LTS?

Tags: thinkpad, external-monitor

I'm trying to connect two external monitors via thinpkad dock. I have tried intalling lightdm and also displaylink drivers for Ubuntu. Still, I can't get it working. Any advice? Do you need more information?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the model numbers of your laptop and the dock. Also, does the problem only occur if you connect both monitors?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem, with or without dock my external monitor was not working with my thinkpad t14s with ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.

You can check your kernel version using

```
uname –sr
```

After updating my Linux kernel to 5.8 ( current latest version ) the problem was gone.